# Find contents of a USB drive on Windows in Python

Tags: python, windows, filesystems

I'm trying to get Python to get files from a USB drive on Windows (from a tablet, actually) and send them through the network. Windows does not offer me a drive letter for the USB device. The device just has a name. There is no option to mount it. diskpart does not see it and mountvol always tell me that "The parameter is incorrect."

The device appears inside of "Computer" under "Portable Devices". I can see the files. They're there, there is no doubt. How can I get Python to grab them? I can't even get to them from the command line. If I try to drag a folder from the drive to a command shell, the mouse pointer turns into a "forbidden" sign. I am given no option to mount or map the device in the Windows GUI.

What can I do?

Comment: Look at it in Administrative Tools | Computer Management | Disk Management and check its properties. You many be able to assign it a drive letter and give it a path so it appears as a folder on another drive there.

Comment: It does not show up in Disk Management. Maybe I should simply reboot... I've been trying to solve this for hours, so if it just needed a reboot, I'll be angry.

Comment: My guess is that this device uses something like PTP instead of mounting as a block device. Windows supports PTP fine, allowing you to copy images from the camera, but of course since a PTP device isn't a drive, it doesn't appear as one in Explorer.

Comment: There are, of course, [Python libraries for PTP](http://code.google.com/p/pyptp/).